# How can I extend a field of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, extend

Suppose I have a List of `Person` (which is a class). It contains about 20 field (Name, Surname, Age, DateOfBirthdate, and so on). So I got this list:

```
var listOfPersons= MyContext.Persons.Cast<Person>();
```

Now, I need to iterate through this List, and for each `Person` adding a new field (which it is not present in the class), called, let's say, `CurrentDateTime`.

I could create a new object, with the new field, and "copy & paste" values from Person to the new Class. Somethings like:

```
PersonNew newPerson = new PersonNew("Name", "Surname", "Age", "DateOfBirthdate", ... "CurrentDateTime");
```

But this is very bad if in the future I change the Person class. So, is there a strategy to "extending Person" with a new field? That takes the Person instance (whatever it is) and adds the new field?

Comment: How long do you want to use this extended `Person`? If it's just for this method you can use an anonymous type.

Comment: Which scenario you have to do this?

Comment: No solution can possibly be safe from arbitrary changes to the base class without modifying the extended class.  It's the "brittle base class problem".

Comment: Yeah, I should use an anonymous type...but how? Can't "extend" it in LINQ

Comment: Is incredible that there isn't a way... it is just a copy to an object to another one "more" big haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create some static method that create `PersonNew` from `Person` using Automapper.

```
public class PersonNew : Person
{
    public static PersonNew CreateFromPerson(Person person, DateTime currentDateTime)
    {
        var newPerson = Mapper.Map<PersonNew>(person);
        newPerson.CurrentDateTime = currentDateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that only certain types of changes to the base class would be supported in this example; complex additions/modifications could result in this solution not working properly.

Comment: @paizza If there are internal properties that are time based, such as storing the date of creation of the object, or if it captures the state of some other type of external resource when created (for example a synchronization context).  Any information not stored in a public property/field, such as information set via a method.  And then of course because you have a new object any existing references to the old object won't refer to the new one, which may not be desirable for you.  Really if your object does much more than just have a bunch of properties, odds are it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution you described works fine.  If you want to keep track of each person's birthday without extending the `Person` class, you might use a Dictionary object

```
var listOfPersons = MyContext.Perons.Cast<Person>();
Dictionary<Person, DateTime> birthdays = new Dictionary<Person, DateTime>    
foreach(Person person in listOfPersons)
{
    birthdays.Add(person, getBirthday(person); 
}
```

Comment: @paizza Well, the point of the answer is that you wouldn't need to.  It may solve your problem even if it's not technically answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to make your class `partial`, and add your field in another `partial` definition of your class:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    ...
}

...

public partial class Person
{
    public DateTime CurrentDateTime { get; set; }
}

...

var listOfPersons = MyContext.Persons.Cast<Person>();
foreach (var person in listOfPersons)
{
    person.CurrentDateTime = ....
}
```

Do note that you will use the *same* instance of your class.

Comment: I cannot put my class Partial. Come with a specify DLL

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest using extension methods for projecting collections instead of iterating. Like that:

```
var newCollection = oldCollection.Select(entity => MakeNewType(entity))
```

Second, it's not completely clear what you mean by "extending Person" with a new field. Here are the couple of ways you can accomplish that.

1) Make another class with the new field and map it to the old one. This is a common scenario for asp.net mvc application where you map models to the appropriate viewmodels. Automapper is useful for these types of scenario (see Sławomir Rosiek anwser)

2) Take advantage of dlr in c# 4+. Yuo will lose the intellisense for dynamic objects, but they canned be passed around functions

```
var newPeople = people.Select(p =>
    {
        dynamic expando = new ExpandoObject();
        expando.Id = p.Id;
        expando.FirtName = p.FirtName;
        /* ... */
        expando.CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now;
        return expando;
    });
```

3) Use Anonymous types. Anonymous types cannot be passed to another functions, so this approach is useful when you need to quickly project data inside a single method and calculate some result

```
var newPeople = people.Select(p => new 
    { 
        Id = p.Id, 
        FirtName = p.FirtName, 
        /* ... */ 
        CurrentDateTime = DateTime.Now 
    });
```

in both cases you can now access newly "created" property:

```
foreach(var p in newPeople)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentDateTime: {0}", p.CurrentDateTime);
}
```

4) If you really need to create a fully featured .net class at runtime you can use [Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.typebuilder.createtype.aspx). This scenario is typically used to create dynamic proxies - subclasses which implement some functionality only known at runtime. Entity framework does this.